# Can't read JSON reply from web service

Tags: jquery, json, webservices-client

So I have a JQuery modal dialog form that takes in a user's registration info, which is then sent as JSON to a web service.  The web service processes the registration request and sends back its own JSON.  This all works, except I can't figure out how to parse the JSON coming back.  Here's the code being called on success of the `$.ajax` method:

```
success: function (data) {
                          console.log(data);
                          console.log(data[0].Reply);
                          $("#spStatus").css('class',     
                             'textGreen').text(data[0].Reply);
```

I'm logging the data to the console to inspect what comes back, and this is what I see :

[image: Console messages]

I can't seem to figure out how to read the info contained in `data`, and the web service is doing its part to return JSON data.  I can't use `JSON.parse` because it's already JSON data that's being returned.  I know this has to be something simple.  Help?

Comment: Try: `console.log(JSON.parse(data.d).Reply);`

Comment: Amir, that was it!  Post this as an answer so I can give you props for it.  Thank you!

Comment: If you control api should fix source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response is a json that has a property `d` which is a json string and therefore:

```
success: function (data) {
    var jsonStr = data.d;
    var json = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

    console.log(json.Reply);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JSON.parse(data), this will map into an object

```
   success: function (data) {
    var obj=JSON.parse(data); <----- this is your object now

}
```

Comment: This is  not correct, because the data coming back is already in JSON format.  This throws an error.  Amir's solution is the correct one.  Calling "JSON.parse(data.d)" is what works.  But I appreciate you taking the time to answer me! (smile)